# How to make Google Maps in black & white

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make google maps in black and white but I can't find a way to do it. However I found this website that has it implemented: http://www.creuna.com/contact/find-us/.

Any clue?

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used it before, but it looks like Google's maps API has a styling section that allows you to really customize the look and feel of your maps:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

There a lot of examples included that should be able to help.

Comment: Yes it does, but you have to play with it to get it to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)
This comes close:

```
 [ { 
  "featureType": "water", 
  "stylers": [ { 
    "color": "#ffffff" } 
    ] 
  },{ 
  "featureType": "landscape", 
  "elementType": "geometry", 
  "stylers": [ { 
    "color": "#000000" } 
   ] 
  },{ 
  "featureType": "administrative", 
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill", 
  "stylers": [ { 
    "color": "#ffffff" } 
    ] 
  },{ 
  "featureType": "administrative", 
  "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", 
  "stylers": [ { 
    "visibility": "simplified" } 
    ] 
  },{ 
  "featureType": "road", 
  "elementType": "geometry", 
  "stylers": [ { 
    "visibility": "off" } 
    ] 
  },{ 
  "featureType": "poi", 
  "elementType": "geometry.fill", 
  "stylers": [ { 
    "color": "#000000" }, { 
    "visibility": "simplified" } 
    ] 
  },{ 
  "featureType": "administrative.province", 
  "stylers": [ { 
    "visibility": "off" } 
    ] 
  },{ 
  "featureType": "road", 
  "elementType": "geometry.stroke", 
  "stylers": [ { 
    "color": "#ffffff" }, { 
    "weight": 2 }, { 
    "visibility": "off" } 
    ] 
  },{ 
  "featureType": "administrative.locality", 
  "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } 
    ] 
  },{ 
  "featureType": "road", 
  "elementType": "labels", 
  "stylers": [ { 
    "visibility": "off" } 
    ] 
  },{ 
  "featureType": "poi", 
  "stylers": [ { 
    "visibility": "off" } 
    ] 
  },{ 
  "featureType": "transit", 
  "stylers": [ { 
    "visibility": "off" } 
    ] 
  },{ 
  "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood", 
  "stylers": [ { 
    "visibility": "off" } 
    ] 
  } 
]
```

[Working Example/proof of concept (using above style)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_maptype-styled-complexBW.html) starting from [this exmaple](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-complex) in the documentation, obviously needs some tuning.  FYI - the example you linked to is a custom map type from [Stamen Maps](http://maps.stamen.com/#toner/12/37.7706/-122.3782).